# How can a Rails 6 app use Sidekiq+Redis for Hotwire/Stimulus but DelayedJob for "worker jobs" such as emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, delayed-job, rails-activejob

For our all of our Rails apps we use DelayedJob for "critical worker jobs" (sending emails etc) because for those jobs we want jobs in our main postgres DB store for simplicity of admin inspection, querying, debugging, persistence, and manual retries if/when needed. DelayedJob has adequate performance for these types of jobs.

But we also want to start using Hotwire, which I understand requires ActionCable, which requires ActiveJobs, and which benefits from the additional job processing speed provided by in-memory Sidekiq+Redis, where persistence and idempotency is not required.

Is there any way to use ActiveJob as the job system for BOTH the DelayedJob-based worker jobs and for the Sidekiq-based ActionCable jobs?

Or does using Sidekiq for Hotwire/ActionCable **require** our DelayedJob-based worker jobs to forego using ActiveJob (and therefore use native DelayedJob jobs)?

Answer (score 2):

[You can have several jobs backends](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#setting-the-backend).

```
 class HotwireActionCableJob < ApplicationJob
   self.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
   # broadcast/stream something through action cable 
 end

 class SomeOtherJob < ApplicationJob
   self.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
 end
```

> Or does using Sidekiq for Hotwire/ActionCable require our
> DelayedJob-based worker jobs to forego using ActiveJob (and therefore
> use native DelayedJob jobs)?

I think you can use ActiveJob throughout everything and simply specify the adapter in the job class.